# Switch between nested tmux sessions

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'm writing a zsh script that setup nested session. I have a session and a session inside that session.

```
sessionA
   sessionB
```

I can create `sessionA` in detach mode `-d` and then call `tmux` inside that to create nested `sessionB` but how to switch to `sessionB`?

I checked `manpage` and there's no `switch-session` option. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would first start a session:

```
tmux new-session -s [session-name] -n [first-tmux-screen-name] -d
```

We can now separate this window in sections by using splitw options:

```
tmux splitw -h
tmux splitw -v
```

we can select a section too:

```
tmux selectp -t0
tmux splitw -v
```

And depending on what we want to display, or run in each nested window, we use the send-key option.  If we want to add a new window to this tmux session we can use this command:

```
tmux new-window -n [name-of-new-window] -t [session-name]
```

zsh works for me:

```
#!/bin/zsh

tmux new-session -s test -n four-screen -d
tmux splitw -h
tmux splitw -v
tmux selectp -t0
tmux splitw -v
```

After your run the script: zsh scriptname.zsh then attach to the session: tmux attach

Comment: Why two `-d` in first session creation?

Comment: was suppose to be a -n sorry.

Comment: Forgot to mention, after you do the last new-window, that is what you will see when you tmux attach -t [session], so to go to the first screen, you would have to do a tmux select-window -t [first-tmux-screen-name] in your script.

Comment: I'm doing in `zsh` script so your answer probably won't help. Right now I have trouble to `rename` nested session. Output keep saying `can't find session <NAME>`

Comment: This is question about how to switch between nested session, your zsh script is about creating a new named session and window then spliting some panes - probably unrelated to the original question but thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tuyen Pham - so, having a script that set up another session that is detached like above, and having another script that does sets up another detached session, where on one of the new windows, it attaches (tmux attach-session -t name of the first detached), isn't what you are looking for?  Note: to attach a new session in the second session, you will have to first unset TMUX, because in the other window you will see an error like this: sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force.  Don't forget to bind a different prefix, for the nested session.

Comment: If you do the above, then you are able to switch to the nested session using the Ctrl-B, and for the nested Session, you can move around that by using for example Ctrl-A,  if you had another nested session, you have to make sure you bind the prefix again lets say making it Ctrl-D and so on.  So switching to nested sessions is basically switching to a new window.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to detach and then attached directly to sessionB.

`tmux attach-session -t sessionB`

Comment: In a script I'd need to switch to `sessionB` silently, so that the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like my question is a little bit not clear.

Here I want to do tasks on nested session but after googling I can achieve that purpose via `send-keys` with option that specify session name to act on. So no need to switch to session that I'd need to work on - I'm in an `zsh` script perspective.