# tmux can't see nested session

Tags: zsh, tmux

Extent of this question: `https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/467025/256195`

But now after run `tmux` inside `sessionA` to create `sessionB`, actually first tmux create a new named session `1` and I'd need to change the name to `sessionB`. How to?

I can change in command line (`zsh>`) and it works but in an `zsh` script, the output keep saying - I just copy and paste from script to command line and in command it works perfectly as I expected:

```
can't find session 1
can't find session 2
```

There's somehow tmux even in order in `zsh` script, `zsh` processes commands in unexpected behavior.

NOTE: I call `tmux` inside the first `window` of `sessionA`.

EDIT: in command line I can see session name `1` exist but when I try to rename it in zsh script it's failed, but in command it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but if you're working with tmux sessions inside tmux sessions, you have to use your binding key sequence twice, then the command key.

For example, if you wanted to split the nested tmux session in two panes, you'd use <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, which assumes you have the default key binding.

Comment: Thanks but all is in an `zsh` script aspect, I'll update the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding now, there's no way to connect to get the right session name of unnamed session when you're in an `zsh` script, meaning after you create an unnamed session by calling `tmux` inside a `tmux` session, you'll be disabled from like `rename-session -t2` - assuming that session indexed from `1`.

But logically the new unnamed session comes from a `window` so should be `rename-session -t1:1:2 <NewNAME>`

`t1:2:1` - `t1` is session `1`, `:1` is window `1`, `:2` is new nested unnamed session.

Before create nested session we have `1` session, `1` window.

So the solution is we create new window and create session inside it with `-s` and `-n` explicitly.